# How to Create and Arrange checkboxes Dynamically inside a container using CSS and html?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I want to create an container which will arrange the checkbox into table columns.
Currently on below html code it is showing me following output

[image: Code Output]

Following is my code:

```html
<label class="control-label text-success">Add Applications</label>
<div class="container border">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm anyClass">
      <div
        class="form-check form-check-inline text-nowrap col-md-3 pl-2"
        *ngFor="let name of applicationList; let srno = index"
        [attr.data-index]="srno"
      >
        <div *ngIf="srno == 1||srno == 4||srno == 7||srno == 10">
          <span class="ml-4"></span>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="srno == 2||srno == 5||srno == 8||srno == 11">
          <span class="ml-5"></span>
        </div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="{{name}}" value="{{name}}" />
        <label class="pt-2 pl-1">{{name}}</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My ts is:

```js
applicationList = [
  'Application 6',
  'Application 7',
  'Application 8',
  'Application 9',
  'Application 10',
  'Application 11',
  'Application 12',
];
```

Here I have hard-coded the margin value based on the srno number in the arraylist.
I want this to be calculated dynamically.
Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: This is more of a css problem, please show your rendered html and css for the checkboxes in a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `hard code` and use flex to solve this.

css:

```css
    .box {
        height: 300px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .box>* {
        flex: 1 1 80px;
    }
```

```html
     <div class="box">
        <div>One</div>
        <div>Two</div>
        <div>Three</div>
        <div>Four</div>
        <div>Five</div>
        <div>Six</div>
        <div>Seven</div>
        <div>Eight</div>
        <div>Nine</div>
      </div>
```

More about flex wrap: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-wrap/
More about flex direction: https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction

A complete simple guide to flex: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

**EDIT** I realize now is not a vertical list. Here the snippet:

```css
      .box {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .box>* {
        flex: 1 1 33%;
    }
```

```html
      <div class="box">
        <div>One</div>
        <div>Two</div>
        <div>Three</div>
        <div>Four</div>
        <div>Five</div>
        <div>Six</div>
        <div>Seven</div>
        <div>Eight</div>
        <div>Nine</div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I have added the css but it is not adding the margin for the 2 & 3 column. As you can see in the above code I have added margin for column 2 & 3 level data.

Comment: you can give a general padding (IE: 20px) on the `box` class and achieve the margin.